# Is there a way to create a shortcut in Finder to an Apple Note?

Tags: macos, finder, applescript, notes.app

I like to use Apple Notes to organize details and checklists for my projects — it's very convenient. However, it would be more convenient if I could access a project note directly from the project folder in Finder. I understand that I can export the note as PDF, but as that I'm constantly adding to and changing my project notes, I'd prefer the shortcut to open the note (or note folder) in the Notes app directly.

**Here's a mockup of what I'd like to accomplish:**

[image]

I've tried to locate the note in Finder, but Apple stores all the notes together in one file. I was just going to create a shortcut to that note (which is still pretty inconvenient). Ideally I like to change the save location for an individual note, share to finder, or create a shortcut link. Can this be done with AppleScript or Automator, or even a simpler method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will like this following **AppleScript** solution.

**STEP 1:** Save this following **AppleScript** code as a **Script File to your /Users/YOUR SHORT NAME/Library/Script Libraries/** folder. *(with the name “Make Link To Note Library.scpt”).*  Just compile the script and save it and don’t even bother running it from **Script Editor**.

This following **AppleScript** will be used as, what is known as a **“Script Library”**.

```
property destinationSuffix : "Contents/Resources/applet.icns"
property iconFile : missing value
property thisApp : missing value
property noteName : missing value

if iconFile = missing value then changeMyIconToNotesIcon()
if noteName = missing value then chooseNote()

try
    tell application "Notes"
        activate
        show note noteName
    end tell
end try

to changeMyIconToNotesIcon()
    set iconFile to path to resource "AppIcon.icns" in bundle ¬
        (path to application "Notes")
    set thisApp to path to me
    set replaceThisIcon to POSIX path of thisApp & ¬
        destinationSuffix as string
    do shell script "cp " & quoted form of POSIX path of iconFile & " " & ¬
        quoted form of replaceThisIcon & " ; touch " & ¬
        quoted form of POSIX path of thisApp
end changeMyIconToNotesIcon

on chooseNote()
    tell application "Notes" to set noteNames to name of notes
    activate
    set noteName to (choose from list noteNames) as text
    return noteName
end chooseNote
```

---

**STEP 2:** Save this following **AppleScript** code as an **application**, with the name, for example “NOTES Make Link To Note Template.app”

```
property loadedScript : load script alias ¬
    ((path to library folder from user domain as text) & ¬
        "Script Libraries:Make Link To Note Library.scpt")

run loadedScript
```

---

Taking this concept one step further, and making life much easier for everyone planning to use the code in my solution. Instead of copying and pasting the code from STEP 2, into a new Script Editor document and saving it as an application etc. , every time you want to create a “Direct Link To A Specific Note” , This following STEP 3 should make the process seamless.

**STEP 3:** Save this following **AppleScript** code as an **application**, with the name, for example “Make Link To Note CREATOR droplet.app”

*Now that we’ve created the `Script Library` file "Make Link To Note Library. scpt”, from STEP 1’s Instructions, we can access its handlers and their commands, directly in this code by inserting the `use` command at the top of this following script.  This line `set noteName to (notesLibrary's chooseNote()) & ".app”` is an example of how to utilize a command from a Script Library file.*

```
use notesLibrary : script "Make Link To Note Library"
use scripting additions

on open theFile
    appletFileIsAcceptable(theFile)
    
    activate
    set saveToFolder to choose folder with prompt ¬
        "Save Your New \"Link To Note.app\" To Which Folder?" multiple selections allowed false ¬
        with invisibles and showing package contents
    
    set noteName to (notesLibrary's chooseNote()) & ".app"
    
    tell application "Finder"
        set duplicatedApp to duplicate item 1 of theFile to saveToFolder
        set name of duplicatedApp to noteName
        open (((saveToFolder as text) & noteName) as alias)
        reveal (((saveToFolder as text) & noteName) as alias)
    end tell
end open

on appletFileIsAcceptable(theFile)
    tell application "System Events" to if name extension of ¬
        item 1 of theFile ≠ "app" then return -- decide if theFile is acceptable
end appletFileIsAcceptable
```

In **Finder**, drag your new created **Script Editor applet from STEP 2**. directly onto the icon of the Droplet from STEP 3. This will create a duplicate of the”Template.app” to a folder of your choosing and name it to the name of the chosen Note and then launch it automatically. When the process is complete, the new “Go To Specific Note.app” will be completely configured and revealed in Finder

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124246/discussion-on-answer-by-wch1zpink-is-there-a-way-to-create-a-shortcut-in-finder).

Answer (score 1):

In Notes app, add a collaborator, and share the link with yourself. Copy that iCloud link and open it in a web browser. No need to sign in. We just care about the URL.

> [image]

(If you can't share the note due to icon being disabled, see https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/icloud/mmc0cd6c83/icloud)

In the address bar, grab the padlock icon and drag and drop it in Finder/ Desktop.

> [image]

Opening that .webloc file will open the note in the Notes app.

---

webloc file is just a plist:
`cat ~/Desktop/note.webloc`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>URL</key>
    <string>https://www.icloud.com/notes/UUID_OF_MY_NOTE</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score -1):

`notes` is a valid url protocol. So you can type `notes://` into the URL bar of a browser, and it will open Notes.app.

However, I haven't found a way of opening the app to a specific note with a specific URL. Using the UUID from the iCloud.com URL of a note doesn't select a given note. It may be possible, so , yes, a bit of a half-answer.